# Run a command within an existing shell window from a second shell window

Tags: 14.04, command-line, window

I have a program that is running on a shell window.
I would like to input command into that shell (using a script) to make the program behave in a certain way.
What would be the command to send a command from one shell to another.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the answer i was looking for was

> xdotool

you can use to search a window (xdotool search), run a command (xdotool key)